# Image not centered inside Paginator in Angular 8

Tags: angular8

I have the following methods in different parent components :

```
viewHelpMultimedia(): void {
    this.dialogService.open(HelpCompComponent, {
      data: {

      },
      header: 'Delete a Certification',
      styleClass: 'edit-popup',
      width: '1000px'
    });
  }

  viewHelpMultimedia(): void {
    this.dialogService.open(HelpCompComponent, {
      data: {

      },
      header: 'Help Steps',
      styleClass: 'edit-popup',
      width: '700px'
    });
  }
```

Those methods only differ in the popup width. Still, in the image we see different layouts. Is the difference in the width causing this[image]

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the width -  `width: '1000px'` vs. `width: '700px'` - was causing the image to not be centered inside Paginator in Angular 8.